# No submit method on form

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have the following problem. I have a script, which creates an `iframe` inside a regular HTML page (with XHTML strict declaration) and inside this `iframe` a `form` is created to request a PDF. Problem is: The `form`-element is lacking the `submit` Method.

The whole script works in a non-strict environment. Does anyone of you have an idea how to fix this? (Switching to non-strict is *not* an option)

Available Libraries:

- PrototypeJS 1.5
- Ext JS 2.1

Iframe and form present in DOM:

[image: Iframe and form present in DOM]

Form does not seem to have submit method

[image: Form does not seem to have a submit method]

Comment: All forms have a submit method, so you have to explain that a lot better, as in what exactly it is you're trying to do ?

Comment: You see, that is exactly the problem. There is a form in the DOM, but it has _no_ submit method. That's the problem.

Comment: Now explain that, how does a form not have a submit method, it's built into HTML and as far as I know it can't be removed. Do you mean there's no submit button, or that there's no action attribute etc? A form can always be submitted, that's the point!

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form with javascript?

Comment: I'm trying to submit the form via javascript. Right after the step in which is created. Which, by the way, works fine. I see it in the DOM and all attributes, inputs are just fine. But assuming the form DOM-object is stored in a variable called `form` then `form.submit` yields `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery you will need to do the following for dynamically created forms:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Binding to the `document` lets you capture events on elements that don't yet exist.

Comment: As stated in the question only ExtJS and Prototype are available.